# Unreal Engine Crashing after a few seconds when a new project is opened

Tags: unreal-engine5

What could be causing Unreal Engine to flicker and crash on my Victus laptop with Windows 11, AMD Ryzen 7 5800H processor, Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 graphics card (6GB), and 16GB of RAM? I have discovered that disabling MFAA in my Nvidia settings resolves the flickering issue. However, after installing Unreal Engine 5.2, the software crashes shortly after opening and working for a few seconds or minutes.

I tried upgrading my graphic and processor drivers to the latest version

Comment: If it crashes, you should receive more Infos from the engine itself. There should be an open window with a stacktrace to the crash location. That would be more helpful than your hardware at the moment. Please do _NOT_ post a picture of the window, post the contents as text. If you do not have debugging symbols installed with the engine, do so first, because without them, the information is basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting back to nvidia driver v528.49 fixed this problem for me.